# How to record not only the app's screen but everything on the screen, including other apps

Tags: ios, swift, screen-recording, replaykit, swift5

I'm trying to implement screen recording app using ReplayKit(Swift). It seems when I'm going outside the app, stops background record. After trying some documents, so far I understand I need to implement Broadcast Extension. If my understanding is right, then So please give me some programming guide about that.

Comment: Please check if this is possible. I don't think it is.

Comment: Already there are some apps in iTunes having that feature. 
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/record-it-screen-recorder/id1245356545

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766698/how-can-i-get-my-app-to-show-in-the-screen-broadcast

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Broadcast Extension. Process is given below:

1. Create a new Xcode project
2. Import ReplayKit
3. Add a UIView in storyboard and change its class to RPSystemBroadcastPickerView in storyboard Identity Inspector
4. File > New > Target > Broadcast Upload Extension
5. Xcode > Project Navigator > Targets > Select Extension > General > Change Deployment Info > Match with your main project
6. Click on View created in step 3 should pop up view for broadcast.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/601/ has more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library

[Screen capture](https://github.com/nirix/swift-screencapture)

OR this one:

[Vid recorder](https://github.com/svhawks/SceneKitVideoRecorder)

```
import ScreenCapture

let recorder = ScreenCapture.recordScreen("/path/to/save/to.mp4")

recorder.start()
...
recorder.stop()

let movieUrl = recorder.destination
```

Otherwise you could do:

```
import ReplayKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(startRecording))
    }

    @objc func startRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

        recorder.startRecording{ [unowned self] (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.stopRecording))
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func stopRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

        recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.startRecording))

            if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
                unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
                self.present(unwrappedPreview, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Replay Kit only record it's current app screen, whenever the app becomes background, the recording will be stopped and that's by-design.

Comment: Above code only record the app screen but not record the entire iPhone screen. Like the app ..
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/go-record-screen-recorder/id1345200849