# How can I get my app to show in the Screen Broadcast?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, replaykit

I've followed all the directions in the [WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/) to get my app to show in the Screen Broadcast.

The steps are supposed to be:

1. Create a new XCode project
2. File > New > Target > Broadcast Upload Extension
3. In the `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller presented (add import `ReplayKit`):

```
let broadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 51, height: 51))
view.addSubview(broadcastPickerView)
view.backgroundColor = .orange // just to make seeing the button easy
```

This is supposed to be the bare minimum required to get the broadcast screen to appear, like below: [image]

**My app does not appear in this list**. I'm almost certain this is some kind of XCode bug. What's interesting is Twilio's Sample App is [here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/tree/master/ReplayKitExample) and if I take their App, and strip it of all of it's source code, and just leave it with the code snippet I have above, I am able to get the Screen Broadcast to work.

So my questions: what am I missing in my steps that are required for screen broadcasting to show my app?

Note: I'm on iOS 14+ and Xcode 12.5.1

Answer (score 3):

Yikes that was a huge time sink. You need to change the "Deployement Info" OS version in the App Extension to be lower. I thought Xcode would just inherit this from the base project.

[image]